# Having problems with add-ons: missing add-ons and incorrect warnings?

Tags: add-on

In the Bleder scripts page for Add Curve Extra Objects:

Installation
This script is in Blender 2.79 Add-Ons menu.

Shift selected all supported levels then I typed "add" in the Add-ons search, no listing for "Add Curve Extra Objects"

Then I typed "curve" in the Add-ons search, no listing for "Add Curve Extra Objects"

Then I typed "add curve" in the Add-ons search, no listing for "Add Curve Extra Objects"

Then I typed "extra" in the Add-ons search, now it shows up.

Also while typing "add" I came across Camera: Add Camera Rigs 
Warning: ! Enable Auto Run Python Scripts in User... 
Checked, it already was checked to be enabled long ago.

Do I bug report this? Or am I not getting something about Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't show up is that the "Add Curve" part of the name of the addon is simply the category in which it is located. If you search the rest of the name "Extra Objects" it will show up.

As far as I know, the warnings for needing other settings show up whether they are necessary or not. Not necessarily a bug, but it could be improved in the future to disappear if everything is in order.